# Making two associations to same model column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I'm pretty new to rails. I'm trying to setup associations to another model in Rails.

I have a User model with columns: id, user_name, email

Now I am trying to create another model Expense which has associations to the user model. The purpose of this model is to create an expense and associate the expense with two different users from the same model User. The association to the second user is to split the amount between the two users.

This is what I'm intending to do while creating the model Expense:

```
$ rails generate model Expense amount:decimal user:references split_with:references
```

Now how do I associate split_with to the User model, since both references associate to the same User model's id of two users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can refer to the same model two different ways:

```
class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :approving_user,
    class_name: 'User'
end
```

This would require columns `user_id` and `approving_user_id` to be present. You can always adjust the generated migration and model code to match this.

As always be sure that `index: true` are set on these columns.

Comment: Is user_id the same as User's id that rails generated or another column entirely?

Comment: Here `expenses.user_id` refers to `users.id` by convention. The default key is always the `id` column of the associated table.